# Finding sibling class from this specific parent to perform an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of this HTML Code in my page - The requirement is that on click of .cta-button, I want the .title div to hide and .alternate-input div to show (both only from the same parent) - The jquery I have written for it triggers all the .alternate-input divs on the page to show. Not sure where am I wrong with this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="label">Abc</div>
    <div class="title">Xyz</div>
    <div class="alternate-input" style="display:none;">
       <input type="text" name="" value="Xyz">
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="cta-button">Call to action</a>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".cta-button").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().find(".title").hide();
    $(this).parent().siblings().find(".alternate-input").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a viewing jquery documentation and this seems to work

```
$(".cta-button").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div').find(".title").hide();
    $(this).closest('div').find(".alternate-input").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.parent().siblings()` is looking at siblings of your `div.row`. You just want to work with `$(this).siblings()`. Also, the `.find()` is unneeded, you can put selectors right in the `.siblings()`.

Try this: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/xVZ46/)

```
$(".cta-button").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".title").hide();
    $(this).siblings(".alternate-input").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/):

```
$(".cta-button").click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".row").find(".title").hide();
    $(this).parents(".row").find(".alternate-input").show();
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMR74/2/)